# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have this error when I try to save an object in database using laravel 5.5.41

Here is my code

```
$game = new Game;
$game->name = $itemFetched["name"];
$game->image = $itemFetched["image"];
$game->wikipediaPageUrl = $itemFetched["wikipediaPageUrl"];
$game->wikipediaPageName = $itemFetched["wikipediaPageName"];
$game->wikipediaPageSlug = $itemFetched["wikipediaPageSlug"][0;
$game->save();
$gameid = $game->id;
```

Here's the error i get:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list'
(SQL:

insert into `games`
(`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `name`, `image`, `wikipediaPageUrl`, `wikipediaPageName`, `wikipediaPageSlug`,
`updated_at`, `created_at`) values
(name, image, metadata, wikipediaPageUrl, wikipediaPageName, wikipediaPageSlug,
    TestName, https://testimageurlvalue.png,
    https://testPageUrlValue.it, testPageNameValue, testPageSlugValue,
2018-08-08 17:08:42,
2018-08-08 17:08:42))
```

I've already tried like this:

```
$gameToImport = array(
    'name' => $itemFetched["name"],
    'image' => $itemFetched["image"],
    'metadata' => json_encode($itemFetched["metadata"]),
    'wikipediaPageUrl' => $itemFetched["wikipediaPageUrl"],
    'wikipediaPageID' => $itemFetched["wikipediaPageID"],
    'wikipediaPageName' => $itemFetched["wikipediaPageName"],
    'wikipediaPageSlug' => $itemFetched["wikipediaPageSlug"]
);

$game = new Game($gameToImport);
$game->save();
```

And switched save() to create() with almost the same result, The only way I've found to insert the record is using the insert method, but I'm unable to get the id of the new record, even $game->id is empty.. I've also tried attaching ->id() or ->id to the insert call without success..

Please someone can help me to understand what is wrong?

Comment: Can you please share your migration for the games table and your model? This seems to be a database related problem, nothing wrong with the code here

Comment: I can post it if needed, but I believe that there is nothing wrong on the database, the games table contains the right number of columns, the problem looks in the query, where some columns are selected (from 0 to 5), looks like the indexes of the array are passed to the query, since some of the column names are in the values

Comment: I'd reconsider your column names.

Comment: @salvob, my guess is you have something strange in your Game model.  Might want to post that, or just recreate it as the default model to rule it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly recommend to use the create method, but if you've already used insert and worked you could try:

```
$game_id = DB::table('games')->insertGetId($itemFetched);
```

or

```
$game_id = DB::table('games')->insertGetId(['name'=>$itemFetched["name"],
'image' => $itemFetched["image"]]);
```

Check here for more information https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#inserts

Answer (score 0):

if you try:

```
$game = new Game;
$game->name = $itemFetched["name"];
$game->image = $itemFetched["image"];
$game->wikipediaPageUrl = $itemFetched["wikipediaPageUrl"];
$game->wikipediaPageName = $itemFetched["wikipediaPageName"];
$game->wikipediaPageSlug = $itemFetched["wikipediaPageSlug"];
$game->save();
$gameid = $game->id;
```

Comment: How will this help? You should explain your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. I realized that I am using protected $attributes in my Eloquent model class. I have removed this protected variable then this problem is resolved.